# iOS, stopping a second button being tapped in an outlet collection, when two are tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutletcollection

I have this weird bug, I wouldn't expect users to do this, but as it's a kids app, therefore I need my app to perform well and not do something unexpected. Which it does.

I have an outlet collection for several buttons and an IBAction.

It's possible for someone, using two fingers, to tap two buttons at once.

I've tried this, however it still runs for both.
Can anyone suggest how I work round this problem ?

```
- (IBAction)btnBtnNum:(id)sender {

for( UIButton *button in self.buttonCollection )
{
    if( sender != button )
    {
        [sender setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't break anything else, you should look at the property multipleTouchEnabled.